# Como fazer o resultado ser publicado no lugar certo?

Tags: php, html

Estou usando o `require` nessa minha página, portanto o resultado está sendo impresso depois do footer, alguém saberia me dizer como resolver, segue o código:

```
<?php

require ("principal.php");

$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "root";
$tabela = "guianortecapixaba";

$conexao = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $tabela);

if ($conexao->connect_error) {
    die("Erro: " . $conexao->connect_error);
}

$busca = $_POST['palavra'];
$cidade = $_POST ['cidade'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'";
$resultados = $conexao->query($sql);


if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        print("<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco']."</br>");
        if( isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>".$fromPerson."</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone']."</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>". $linha['email']."</br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}

$conexao->close();

?>
```

Comment: É bem simples  o seu footer esta dentro do principal.php eu suponho .... e a execução esta sendo feita depois, interessante seria levar esse bloco de php para um arquivo separado e fazer o include aonde ele deveria trazer o resultado

Comment: Dê um exemplo ai pois não consegui, eu ainda estou aprendendo por isso tamanhas dificuldades

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione a parte do footer aonde deveria aparecer a informação assim vou conseguir te ajudar

Comment: Não é no footer que é para aparecer a informação, mas sim na coluna principal da página, portanto as informações estão sendo imprimidas depois do footer

Comment: Respondido veja se lhe ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então vamos la, crie um novo arquivo com o conteúdo, removendo o conteudo do arquivo atual:

Vamos chamar hipoteticamente o arquivo de **retorno.php** (nome deve ser alterado a sua necessidade)

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "root";
$tabela = "guianortecapixaba";

$conexao = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $tabela);

if ($conexao->connect_error) {
    die("Erro: " . $conexao->connect_error);
}

$busca = $_POST['palavra'];
$cidade = $_POST ['cidade'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'";
$resultados = $conexao->query($sql);


if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        print("<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco']."</br>");
        if( isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>".$fromPerson."</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone']."</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>". $linha['email']."</br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}
```

Após isto dentro do **principal.php** exatamente no ponto aonde deve retornar esses dados você ira inserir:

```
<?php
    require ("retorno.php");
```

Lembrando que **retorno.php** é o nome que demos a este novo arquivo, creio que isto resolve seu problema.